# Is it possible to decode filenames from event tracing?

Tags: linux, performance, ftrace

I am currently debugging performance using Linux ftrace and I noticed a few events of the following form appearing in the trace.

```
sys_open(filename: 42130b, flags: 441, mode: 1b6)
```

Is it possible to decode this filename into a hierarchical name in the filesystem?

Alternatively, is there a configuration parameter that would automatically show the decoded versions of the filename?

Comment: are you using "filtering" arguments to `ftrace`? If so, include them in your Q. Interesting problem. Good luck!

Comment: All events are enabled. Function tracer nop.